# Cross server form data to be sent in a secure way

Tags: php, forms, security, post, cross-domain

I am **sending some important info from a form in 1 website to another** (2 different subdomains in the same server). Because of the receiving end being in a different subdomain I can't make it require logging in (like I would if it was in the same) and that makes my receiving end very vulnerable because it can easily be called in from another place to do it's work bypassing my form (which is very bad).

**How can I make this more secure?** Can I send some sort of security token along with my form that cannot be intercepted (because I assume if the $_POST array just contained a security token it could be easily intercepted making it useless. Correct me if I'm wrong here) or maybe limit the receiving end to only accept data from one specific place (like a certain url or IP)?

This is an important project so I don't mind going overkill with it's security in it.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't make it require logging in

Yes, you can. Single sign on across domains is a pretty well documented problem, and you aren't even dealing with multiple domains. It is [even easier across subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain).

> Can I send some sort of security token along with my form

Yes. Generate the token. Store it on the server. Put it in the form. Submit the form.

> that cannot be intercepted

Submit the form over SSL.

(Unless you mean you want to store the person who controls the browser from intercepting it, in which case you are out of luck. If you are sending data via the browser, then you are placing it under the control of the browser owner. If you can't trust them, then you can't trust the data.)

---

> Can you tell me of a good way to limit targetForm.php to receiving info only from a.domain.com/form.php or it's ip?

You are looking for a defence against CSRF. You'll need to implement a session across your subdomains (which you can do, see the above notes on cookies) and then use a [synchroniser token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) (which you store in the form and the session and then compare in `form.php`).

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a simple approach:

1. Form is on subdomain A, lets say a.domain.com/form.php
2. Form submits data to the same subdomain or even script (why not), a.domain.com/form.php
3. form.php uses cURL to send a POST request to b.domain.com/targetForm.php
4. b.domain.com/targetForm.php accepts requests only from b.domain.com's IP, or something like that

That way you can still require users to be logged in at a.domain.com in order to submit the form, and when everything is OK then push that data to b.domain.com/targetForm.php, which you'd make to accept requests from a.domain.com only.

Comment: I am making the first 3 steps but am sending the post data using this method instead ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php ) . My problem is exactly with making step 4. Can you tell me of a good way to limit targetForm.php to receiving info only from a.domain.com/form.php or it's ip?

Comment: You should be able to see the IP at `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` (remote server's IP at the script you're submitting the data to). Also, if both subdomains can access the same database server, for example, then you can also pass some bit of information that you can use at the target subdomain in order to authenticate the user (some sort of token, session id, whatever).